# Mongo: Query object not related to another (many to many)

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many

I have this schema in MongoDB, many to many relation between Team and Player:

Team:

```
{
    name: "Team1"
    players: ["1", "2"]
}
{
    name: "Team2"
    players: ["1"]
}
```

Player:

```
{ id: "1", name: "Player1"}
{ id: "2", name:"Player2"}
{ id: "3", name:"Player3"}
```

I would like to query all the players that don't belong to any team. Whats the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that in two steps.  In the shell:

```js
// Find all the player ids that are part of teams
var ids = db.teams.distinct('players')

// Find all the players with ids not in that set.
db.players.find({id: {$nin: ids}})
```

returns:

```js
{ "_id": ObjectId("5137947e0f26e0cc03fc3735"), "id": "3", "name": "Player3" }
```